# about possion gamma and exponential distribution

Tags: probability

about possion gamma and exponential distribution
[image]

can someone explain how to sub in the numbers? 
i tried subbing in numbers and the outcome its not the same as the answer.

maybe I'm not doing it correct .

I'm getting 1/2 e^-1.5 for the first question .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exponential distributions deal with the amount of time between events.  The first problem is exponential with $\lambda = .5$. Since we are dealing with more than 3 hours between calls, we have
$$P(X\ge{3})=\int_{3}^{\infty}.5e^{-.5x}dx=-e^{-.5x}|_{3}^{\infty}=0-(-e^{-.5(3)})=e^{-1.5}=.2231$$
THe second problem, you need to know that the mean and standard deviation of an exponential distribution is $\frac1{\lambda}$.  Since this number is $2$, $(.5^{-1})$ then the we can find 
$$P(X\ge\mu+\sigma)=P(X\ge{4})=\int_{4}^{\infty}.5e^{-.5x}dx=-e^{-.5x}|_{4}^{\infty}=0-(-e^{-.5(4)})=e^{-2}=.1353$$
EDIT:  Continued answer.
For questions 3 and 4, we are talking about Poisson, since we are wanting the number of events given a mean and a particular interval.  Since we know the mean in one hour is .5, the mean in a 3 hour interval is 1.5.  Thus we will use $\lambda=1.5$.  Now we are looking for exactly 2 calls in three hours, thus, using Poisson,
$$P(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}=\frac{1.5^2e^{-1.5}}{2!}=.2510$$
Now for 4, we have our $\lambda=1$ since it is in a 2 hour interval.  The mean and variance for Poisson are both $\lambda$, so $\mu+2\sigma=1+2\sqrt1=3$.  Since we need fewer than 3 we have
$$P(X\le2)=\sum_{k=0}^{2}\frac{1^ke^{-1}}{k!}=e^{-1}\left(1+1+\frac1{2}\right)=.9197$$

Comment: so the e^-0.5x is acquired by e^-3/2 where 3 is the hour between 2 successful events and 2 is the expect value which is 1/lambda

Comment: Exponential distribution gives the probability of waiting time between events.  The 3 represents the lowest bound for the problem since that is given information.  You were close in your original answer but integration cancels the $1/2$ since $\int{e^{ax}dx}=\frac{e^{ax}}{a}+C$.

Comment: and can you tell me in what situation to use poisson, gamma,??

Comment: See above for edits.

Comment: I will add that the exponential is a special case of the gamma where k=1 (shape parameter).  In a nutshell, the gamma distribution measures the waiting times between multiple poisson events (exponential just between two events).  Use gamma when you have waiting times between multiple events.